# Listen to RootScope Event on Route Change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-routing

In single page application, I am using HTML5 Mode routes. Lets say `someDomain.com/#/credits` becomes `someDomain.come/credits`. Changing the routes on the click of tab.

So lets say I have tab1 tab2 tab3 so routes fr corresponding tabs are someDomain.com/tab1 someDomain.com/tab2 someDomain.com/tab3. Some data needs to be fetched across all the routes so created a service for the same and return promise object. When the object gets resolved I am throwing `$rootscope.emit` event and listening it using `$on` on corresponding tabs. Since my tab1 tab2 and tab3 data is dependant on the service data, I listen to the event and then only performs the corresponding tasks.

Problem is When I click the Tab2 from tab1 page or vice versa $rootscope event gets lost and tab2 doesn't know about any such event. Am I missing something over here? I am very new to angularJS but not able to find an appropriate solution for the same. Is this because of html5 route mode or normal behaviour in routes? Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show relevant code. We have no idea what events you are using or where you are using them. Sounds like you need to use routeParams instead of events

Comment: @charlietfl Yes route resolve was the solution. Figured it out. Thanks for your help man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So whats happening is child controller is not called when the event is broadcasted, so registering of `$on` child listener is not there. Eg: While on tab1, tab2 controller is not loaded so broadcast event which is thrown during tab1 page (even if it is thrown on rootscope) will not listen to the $on on tab2 and tab3. So loading of children listeners before parent broadcast is necessary.

So I have moved to route resolve property and this solves my case. For reference: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx